# Json transformers - new field from 2 existing ones

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Using the json API, how can I write a transformer for the following:

```
{
"name":"John Doe",
"number":22
}
```

to

```
{
"name":"John Doe",
"number":22,
"slug":"John-Doe-22"
}
```

This is doable using string manipulation, but how do I pick the values from the 2 fields and apply that to them?

Comment: Did you read the documentation about [JSON transformers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaJsonTransformers)? The above documentation is for Play 2.1.x, are you using that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
val json = Json.obj(
   "name" -> JsString("John Doe"),
   "number" -> JsNumber(22)
)

val transformed = 
   json.transform(
      __.json.update(
        (__ \ 'slug).json.put(JsString(
          (json \ "name").as[String].replace(' ', '-') + "-" + (json \ "number").as[Int]
        ))
      )
   ).get

Ok(transformed.toString())
//{"name":"John Doe","number":22,"slug":"John-Doe-22"}
```

[Here](http://mandubian.com/2012/10/29/unveiling-play-2-dot-1-json-api-part3-json-transformers/) is nice post about play json trasformations.

Comment: What is `Ok` here? Where does it get imported from?

Comment: It's play framework method, to use it just extend play.api.mvc.Controller